# How can I put a CSS variable for the users screen width into a calc function?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-variables, css-calc

My website is designed on a larger monitor and has a screen width of 2560px (Samsung 32"). Therefore it must be scaled down to appear properly on any smaller screen; for example, a common laptop with a 17" screen has a pixel width of 1366px.  So, by dividing 1366 / 2560 we get the right scale percentage of .53 for use in a CSS `transform:scale(calc(1366 / 2560));` formula.

The entire page is wrapped in a div that I have called .omniScale

```
.omniScale {
    display: table; 
    margin:0 auto;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform:scale(calc(1366 / 2560));
}
```

This works just great, however the 1366 has to change dynamically on page load to the width of the user’s device no matter if it may be a tablet, laptop, mid-size desktop monitor or larger on up to a large television.

Using 100vw instead of the hardwired number does not work.  I don't want to use JavaScript, if avoidable, so has to work for those who have js turned off.

Comment: Why does `100vw` “*not work*,” given that it should give an accurate pixel width of your user’s window size?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :]

Sadly at this moment there is no mechanism to calculate **integer ratio** of two **length** values in pure CSS (`calc(100vw / 2560px)` won't work, because you can divide length only with integer to get other length, not with other length to get integer).

So if you want to get ratio of your reference element to actual viewport, JavaScript seems to be the only option.  Reasonable approach would be use JS just to set CSS custom property and let styles do the rest:

```js
function setScaleRatio() {
  viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  fullWidth = 2560 + 200;
  // (2560 is reference size, +200 just to make sure we'll see right border in this example)
  scaleRatio = viewportWidth / fullWidth;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--ratio', scaleRatio);
};
setScaleRatio();
window.addEventListener('resize', setScaleRatio);
```

```css
[style]::before {
  content: attr(style);
}
```

```html
<div style="
width: 2560px;
transform: scale(var(--ratio));
transform-origin: top left;
font-size: 100px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the efforts to help.  If .js is the only way, I guess I'll just have to accept that portion of all users who won't have it turned on as kicked out.  Hard to believe that in 2020 there is no easy way to do this.  Seems to me that this would be a very common need for developers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the right approach. to make something responsive to all screens it is best to use percentages and `@madia`.

for more info: https://blog.froont.com/9-basic-principles-of-responsive-web-design/

example:

```
.container {
    width: 2560px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px) {
    .container {
        width: 1366px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .container {
        width: 900px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that 100vw does not work because it renders a % value, not pixels.

Comment: yes, that's why its more comfortable to use percentages and `@madia`

Comment: yes, also tried @media with a css variable but didn't work either.  Maybe my syntax wrong?    --x = @media(width)   .. ..  transform:scale(calc(--x / 2560));

Comment: don't use scale, transform styling are graphics and not vectorized. use normal width and for @madia read https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Are you saying like this?::::: @media screen {  omniScale {   width: 100%;
  }
}

Comment: edited answer with @media, all elements in the `.container` should work with percentages

Comment: thanks for the pointers.. though I'm not seeing a necessity to call out containers for every conceivable device width.  2560 is an anchor value because it is as designed. For everything else it's a matter of dividing the users screen width in pixels as a number by 2560.  I  want my website to stay put as designed and not thrown into a junkyard heap as with flex or grid.. everything inside of .omniScale is nailed in place with position absolute...  it's just that the mother wrapper ".omniScale"  scales to the users screen width and everything in it goes for the ride.